# Stack Overflow when Disposing a Managed Resource

Tags: c#, .net, unity-container, stack-overflow, idisposable

I have a simple wrapper for a Unity IoC container (a temporary use of Service Locator [anti-]Pattern to introduce DI to a legacy codebase), and since the `IUnityContainer` in Unity implements `IDisposable` I wanted to expose that through the wrapper as well.

The wrapper is simple enough:

```
public class IoCContainer : IIoCContainer
{
    private IUnityContainer _container;

    public IoCContainer(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        _container = container;
    }

    public T Resolve<T>()
    {
        return _container.Resolve<T>();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    ~IoCContainer()
    {
        Dispose(false);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
            if (_container != null)
            {
                _container.Dispose();
                _container = null;
            }
    }
}
```

`IIoCContainer` is the domain interface which has nothing but `T Resolve<T>()` on it, and of course `IDisposable`.  So everything below that one method is simply the implementation of `IDisposable` [as I found it on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms244737.aspx).

However, when `.Dispose()` is called on this object (such as when exiting a `using` block), a `StackOverflowException` is raised.  Debugging, it looks like the call stack repeats between:

- `Dispose()` is called on this class
- Which calls `Dispose(true)` on this class
- Which calls `Dispose()` on `IUnityContainer`
- Which calls `Dispose()` on this class

[image]

**I can resolve this** in this case by putting a `bool` flag on the class, setting it on the first line of `Dispose()`, and checking for it in `Dispose(bool)`, so the recursion ends at its second iteration.  But **why does this happen in the first place?**  I can only assume I've either missed something obvious or misunderstood something about resource disposal.  But what?

Comment: have you added `IIoCContainer` to the unity container?

Comment: This may be a dumb question, but are `this` and `_container` the same object?

Comment: @Rhumborl: I think that may be the issue, now that you point it out.  The conventions used when registering include the assembly which contains this very implementation.  So perhaps the `UnityContainer` is holding a reference to a resolved `IoCContainer` and is disposing it?  I'll test and see what I can find.  I can't explicitly think of a case where I would need to *resolve* an instance of this container, so it may be safe to exclude it from the registration.

Comment: @adv12: Checked, that is not the case.

Comment: Something very fishy going on in the object model of course, try to not ignore that.  A very simple way to break the recursion is to set the `_container` field to null *before* you dispose it.  And do ask yourself why you implemented the disposable pattern, your finalizer does absolutely nothing useful.

Comment: If you resolve to a IoCContainer, then you have definitely coded an infinite recursion. Your approach to resolve it with the bool flag is the correct one.

Comment: @HansPassant: I'm certainly open to advice on that.  This implementation of `IDisposable` simply came from noticing that this object owns an `IDisposable` resource and I figured I should maintain that interface.

Comment: @Rhumborl: That appears to have been the root cause here.  I still have some work to do outside the scope of this question to better understand how to use the `Dispose()` method on WebApi's `IDependencyResolver` (which initially triggered this), but that's of course a separate issue entirely.  At the very least, an `IoCContainer` can now be successfully disposed.  Thanks!

Comment: Writing a finalizer has been wrong 99.9% of the time since .NET 2.0 added the SafeHandle classes.  The odds that a DI container ever owns an unmanaged resource are also zero.  Use courageous programming, declare your class *sealed*.  If you don't want to then the next courageous thing to do is to declare your Dispose() method *virtual* so a derived class can override it.

Comment: @HansPassant Do we ever need to write finalizer if we only delegate disposal to another resource? After all if that another resource needs finalization - it would have finalizer itself.

Comment: @HansPassant: I'll definitely look into this more, thanks.  Currently the `Dispose(bool)` is indeed virtual, though I have no objection to alternatively making this a `sealed` class because nothing should ever inherit from this.  (It's only a temporary measure anyway.)  All I'm really looking to do here is "implement `IDisposable` the right way" to dispose of the `IDisposable` owned by this object, and Googling that exact phrase yields countless examples of this code, particularly from MSDN.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is implementation of `IDisposable` within `UnityContainer`. It is obvious that you cannot dispose your parent container. It will iterate through all registrations and dispose them if they are also `IDisposable`. Take a look:

```
protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing) 
{ 
   if (disposing) 
   { 
       if (lifetimeContainer != null) 
       { 
           lifetimeContainer.Dispose(); 
           lifetimeContainer = null; 

           if (parent != null && parent.lifetimeContainer != null) 
           { 
               parent.lifetimeContainer.Remove(this); 
           } 
       } 

       extensions.OfType<IDisposable>().ForEach(ex => ex.Dispose()); 
       extensions.Clear(); 
   } 
}
```

Comment: Indeed, as discovered as well via comments on the question, the `UnityContainer` instance was holding a referenced to a resolved `IoCContainer`.  So that last `ForEach()` was the source of the recursion.  I've removed `IoCContainer` from the Unity configuration, since I can't think of a reason why it would ever need to resolve an instance of itself.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I believe the problem here is that you are not supposed to be disposing of the container instance that implements `IUnityContainer` within your class.

The instance is being passed on as a resource to your class, but it was created externally, so whatever code created that instance is the one that should be in charge of disposing of it properly.

Your `IoCContainer` should only be concerned with disposing of resources it creates internally.

Comment: Devoid of other context I would agree.  However, in this case this object "owns" this resource.  The resource was given to it by a static initialization function which registers the `UnityContainer`, wraps it in this class, and returns it to the caller.

Comment: Whoever creates the resource owns it, not who uses it, @David. That is the whole point of using an IoC container. It is the container that manages the lifetime (and disposal) of the objects it creates.

Comment: Let me clarify, whoever created the IUnityContainer instance that gets passed to the wrapper in your code should be the one to dispose of it at some point.

Comment: Again, devoid of context, I would agree.  I guess I could rectify that in this situation by moving the static initialization function from its current neighboring class to this class.  That would satisfy this semantic point, but the issue itself would still remain.

Comment: You mention the initialization function is static. Can you please post the code for this function? It almost sounds like you don't even need to worry about this anyways.

Comment: That's really outside the scope of the issue at hand.  The semantics of *how* or *where* this class gets instantiated can be debated and refactored at length, but the end result of an otherwise atomic operation is that an instance of this class exists, and it wraps/owns a disposable resource.  Nothing else has a reference to this wrapped object.  This class wholly owns it.  When this class is disposed, it should dispose the resource it owns.

Comment: Regardless of the semantics, you only dispose of resources YOU create. If you want your wrapper class to dispose of the underlying container, then your class needs to create the underlying container. By the way, after taking another look, I suspect what is happening here is that your wrapper class itself is being managed by the container it uses, which is probably what causes the loop.

Comment: @Juan: Disposal *can* only be accomplished by code which knows when an object will no longer be needed.  If the creator of an object isn't going to know when it's no longer needed, the only way proper disposal can occur will be if the creator of the object can give responsibility to something that will know when the object is no longer needed.

Comment: It's been a while @supercat but I think he was passing the object as a resource from by a DI but stated that only that class uses it. The whole point of using a DI container IS that the container will manage the creation and lifetime of the objects for you. If he wants his internal class to destroy the object, he should let the internal class create the object. That was my point. In this particular case he happens to know only that class uses it but what happens down the road when the next developer comes and assumes the DI container is managing it and it gets disposed?

Comment: You simply cannot dispose of an external object that was passed on to you as a resource because you don't know if someone else still needs it.

Comment: @Juan: In cases where a container will be the only thing that knows when objects are no longer needed, the container will need to provide a means by which it can be given responsibility for the objects in question.  A lot of .NET classes are sloppy in this regard, but in many cases what's needed is to have a way of adding an object without transferring responsibility and a way of adding an object with transferred responsibility, for cases where code creating the object knows that it should be kept around as long as the container, but has no idea how long that will be.

Comment: @Juan: As an example of a place that pattern should have been--but wasn't used--consider the background image property of a WinForms control.  Sometimes it will be set to a pre-existing image that should last as long as the application (and should not be disposed by the control), but sometimes one needs to set it to a new image which exists purely to be used by the control, and should exist only as long as the control is using it.  The creator of the image may have no idea when the control's image will be set to something else, so the control would be the only thing that could dispose the img.

Comment: Agreed. However, if you take another look at his implementation, you will realize that the IoCContainer class is a concrete implementation that uses a Unity Container as the underlying source. I bet you my house that he was trying to get an instance that implements his interface (IIoCContainer) from the same Unity container he is using to initialize the concrete object, which results in an instance of this class. When he disposes of the class, the class tries to dispose of the Unity container, which in turn is tracking the class itself, causing the circular reference.

Answer (score 2):

This is not the best answer probably, but if you have no controll over implementation of `IUnityContainer` and it *have* to dispose `IoCContainer` you can always break the chain of recurrection in at least two, valid ways:

```
protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (disposing)
        if (_container != null)
        {
            var tempContainer = _container;
            _container = null;
            tempContainer.Dispose();
        }
}
```

or

```
private bool isDisposed = false;
protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if(isDisposed) return;
    isDisposed = true;

    if (disposing)
        if (_container != null)
        {
            _container.Dispose();
            _container = null;
        }
}
```